# Xamarin Android crashes while trying to login LinqToTwitter

Tags: android, xamarin, linq-to-twitter

I'm encountering some really frustrating issue while trying to login to Twitter with LinqToTwitter on Xamarin.Android.

Exception is: "System.NullReferenceExceptionObject: reference not set to an instance of an object"

Here's a report from Xamarin.Insight:
[image]

So **exactly** the same code works for iOS and I'm wondering why it doesn't work for Android.

Here's full console log of this issue:

```
Could not find `System.Reactive.Linq` referenced by assembly `LinqToTwitterPcl, Version=3.1.2.18329, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=957107be965c25d9`.
assertion failed: 15D21 13C75: libxpc.dylib + 71630 [60B4AA4E-F817-3C94-B4DA-0620CC9847B6]: 0x7d
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7e945f00 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7e945f00 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7e945f00 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7e945f00 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7e945f00 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7e945f00 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7e945f00 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
Warning: Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at LinqToTwitter.XAuthAuthorizer+<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0002d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at LinqToTwitter.XAuthAuthorizer+<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0002d] in <filename unknown>:0 <---
Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
```

And the problem is that I'm not sure where's exactly this problem.Seems like some missing libs or assemlies.

Really hope for Mr.Mao's help as creator of this cool lib.

Comment: can you find `System.Reactive.Linq.dll` somewhere?

Comment: @Stefan Yep it's included in shared project. And there's a link to it. So I'm wondering what can be wrong? Because iOS version works perfect with it.

Comment: Have you referenced in the Android project as well?

Comment: @Jan What does your code look like with the XAuthorizer? Please remember to *not* include your secret keys.

Comment: @JoeMayo Thanks for quick reply! I really appreciate your time! I've attached the code snippet in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code for custom LoginPage looks very similar to iOS version:

```
public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    bool showLogin = true;
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object s, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(s, e);

        var activity = this.Context as Activity;

        if (showLogin && App.User == null)
        {
            showLogin = false;

            //Twitter with oauth1 
            var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
                consumerKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
                consumerSecret: "xxxxxxxxx",
                requestTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"), 
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"), 
                accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
                callbackUrl: new Uri("https://mobile.twitter.com")
            );

            auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    App.User = new UserDetails();
                    // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
                    App.User.Token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["oauth_token"];
                    App.User.TokenSecret = eventArgs.Account.Properties["oauth_token_secret"];
                    App.User.TwitterId = eventArgs.Account.Properties["user_id"];
                    App.User.ScreenName = eventArgs.Account.Properties["screen_name"];
                    App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
                }
            };

            activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code with XAuthAuthorizer:

```
private static TwitterContext GetTwitterContext()
    {
        var auth = new XAuthAuthorizer()
        {
            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                ConsumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                OAuthToken = App.User.Token,
                OAuthTokenSecret = App.User.TokenSecret,
                ScreenName = App.User.ScreenName,
                UserID = ulong.Parse(App.User.TwitterId)
            },
        };
        auth.AuthorizeAsync();

        var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);
        return ctx;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the call to AuthorizeAsync:

```
private static **async Task<TwitterContext>** GetTwitterContext()
{
    var auth = new XAuthAuthorizer()
    {
        CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
        {
            ConsumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            ConsumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            OAuthToken = App.User.Token,
            OAuthTokenSecret = App.User.TokenSecret,
            ScreenName = App.User.ScreenName,
            UserID = ulong.Parse(App.User.TwitterId)
        },
    };

    **await auth.AuthorizeAsync();**

    var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);
    return ctx;
}
```

In addition to the await, you need to make sure your call chain is properly decorated with async/await, which is normal for async code. LINQ to Twitter is async, so that's the way you should code it.

Besides seeing that your code wasn't async, I already suspected what the problem is from your stack trace. The NullReferenceException during MoveNext was a giveaway because it means the internal state of the async code is inconsistent. This happens because the nature of async is that it will return up the call stack as soon as you invoke a method, unless you await it. In your case, it looks like the calling thread returned before the async operation was complete, causing the exception.

The reason why you aren't seeing the same problem in your iOS app is because of the nature of threading. In that case, if you aren't awaiting your async calls, you're likely to eventually encounter the same type of exception. That's because there's a race condition between the call and the return and it's unpredictable - so it isn't surprising to see different behavior in different situations/devices/platforms, when making async coding mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wasn't clear, where exactly problem occurs. This NullReferenceException appears at the beggining - when login page should occur, but it doesn't. And I'm wondering is that problem because of lack of asynchronous or something else? Because (maybe I'm wrong) I just don't see where here a can make something async:

```
public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    bool showLogin = true;
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object s, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(s, e);

    var activity = this.Context as Activity;

    if (showLogin && App.User == null)
    {
        showLogin = false;

        //Twitter with oauth1 
        var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
            consumerKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
            consumerSecret: "xxxxxxxxx",
            requestTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"), 
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"), 
            accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
            callbackUrl: new Uri("https://mobile.twitter.com")
        );

        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                App.User = new UserDetails();
                // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
                App.User.Token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["oauth_token"];
                App.User.TokenSecret = eventArgs.Account.Properties["oauth_token_secret"];
                App.User.TwitterId = eventArgs.Account.Properties["user_id"];
                App.User.ScreenName = eventArgs.Account.Properties["screen_name"];
                App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
            }
        };

        activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
    }
}
}
```

Should I even do something async here?

Of course I've changed the code of GetTwitterContext(), but I use it later, for querying and other things. And as I suppose the problem is here, on loginpage, because its the first what's happening to app - it shows this standart twitter webview for authorizing.
I understood what you've explained in your previous post but I suspect that I don't fully understand where the problem here.

Thank you for your time and patience.